# Are there translation probabilities for major language pairs?

Tags: nlp, language, translation

Are there reasonable alignment probability files for major language pairs?

Specifically, given a *target language* and a *target word/phrase*, what are the [translation equivalents](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryoflinguisticTerms/WhatIsTranslationalEquivalence.htm) in other major languages and what are the associated distributional probabilities of that word. For example, given language *English* and phrase "to be" the results for *Spanish* might be: *ser* (0.55) and *estar* (0.45).

Most likely from GIZA++ train (`[prefix].actual.ti.final`), but others would be interesting too.

Ideally news or user-generated data, but any reasonably large domain or a mix of domains is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

There are probabilities for English with all EU languages (except Irish and Croatian) available [here](http://metashare.tilde.com/repository/search/?q=Probabilistic+bilingual+dictionaries).

Inside the .zip for each language pair English-X you will find files lex.e2x and lex.x2e.

They contain strictly unigram-to-unigram probabilities, which maintains simplicity but is an inherent limitation.

The files are the result of a [2014 paper by Aker, Lestari Paramita, Pinnis & Gaizauskas](http://staffwww.dcs.shef.ac.uk/people/A.Aker/papers/dictionaryPaper2014.pdf).

[image]

I also found [a repo on GitHub](https://github.com/idiap/act/tree/master/Samples) which includes English-Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to find *translation equivalents* is from **Project Panlex** -- According to their website, their mission is:

> "To make panlingual lexical translation possible, the PanLex project
>   is constructing a database designed to include translations among all
>   words (and word-like phrases) of the languages of the world. We are
>   gathering translations from thousands of dictionaries, glossaries,
>   vocabularies, thesauri, word lists, wordnets, and other such published
>   and unpublished sources. We subject the translations found there to a
>   set of standards, so they may be combined into a unified network."

Here is a [page linking to various web interfaces](http://panlex.org/try/) as well as actual [downloadable data](http://dev.panlex.org/db/) in csv, json, and xml formats.

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell, it has no translation probabilities, correct?  ie implicit probability > 0.0.